# How does Tam know who "Maighdin" really is?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Gathering Storm*, Rand meets with his father. A part of their conversation includes Perrin's exploits:

> Rand's mood darkened slightly. "Wait. Perrin has been using Two Rivers folk?"
>
> Tam nodded. "He needed us. That boy's put on a balancing act to impress any menagerie performer. What with the Seanchan and the Prophet's men, not to mention the Whiteclocks and the queen-"
>
> "The queen?" Rand said.
>
> "Aye," Tam said. "**Though she says she's not queen anymore. Elayne's mother**."
>
> <sub>*The Gathering Storm*, Chapter 47</sub>

It's undoubtedly clear he is referring to Morgase.

In the following book *Towers of Midnight*, Perrin mentions that Gaebril was actually Rahvin in disguise. "Maighdin" hears this and drops her teacups.

> Maighdin stood, looking stunned, arms at her sides. The fallen tray lay on the ground before her.
>
> <sub>*Towers of Midnight*, Chapter 21</sub>

This whole exchange shows that at least Perrin and Faile and most of the camp didn't know of Maighdin's true identity (and later on when she *does* reveal herself). But how would Tam al'Thor been able to figure out beforehand? Only a handful of people who had been travelling with Morgase knew who she was, and Tam definitely wasn't part of that handful.

At first I thought that the timelines hadn't caught up as with previous books, but then I remembered that Rand had already undergone his ascension when he meets the farmer Alden in the prologue. Coupled with the fact that chapter 13 clearly shows Rand returning after his ascension.

**So how does Tam know Morgase?**

Comment: I may be misremembering this, but didn't he serve under her in his military career? Don't really have the books at hand to look this up atm.

Comment: I'll make an answer later when I have a chance to look at the books but there is definitely some continuity weirdness between those two books. It's like some of ToM really should have been chapters in the previous book.

Comment: @Kakturus IIRC he serves under Illian as a Captain in the Aiel War. There’s a quote of that by Moiraine somewhere...

Comment: Tam meets Rand AFTER Morgase's identity is revealed by Galad.

Comment: I concur with @Shanty, the time slicing on the books gets a little out of whack as they progress, due to the tendency of individual plot lines to leap forward while others are barely touched in a given book.

Comment: The "weirdness" might be explained with The Gathering Storm being the last book that Jordan wrote, though he probably had other chapters ready. And then the editors and Sanderson had to pick up the pieces.

Comment: @Shanty I see, I get it now. So it's just a timeline discontinuity. I'd be happy to answer my own question now unless someone would like to post one?

Comment: I vaguely recall that almost immediately after Rand met with his father, he went to the mountain. After Morgase was revealed, there were many more events, and then Perrin saw Rand on the mountain. If I recall correctly, this would prove the order of events is correct.

Comment: Apparently a similar question about this discrepancy has been asked before. I'll just go ahead and vtc my question since the answer there answers my question perfectly.